# Python: vectorise function over two multi-dimensional arrays simultaneously

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

In python, it is simple to vectorise a function `f(x)` of a scalar `x` over a single array `a1`: just use `f(a1)`. But suppose I have two (or in principle, multiple) arrays `a1, a2` having the same shape `Nx3`, and I want to vectorise a function, `g(x,y)` with `x,y` scalars, simultaneously over both. Something like `g(a1,a2)`, which will return an object again with the common dimension `N`.

EDIT:
If `a1`, `a2` are both 1-dimensional, this becomes trivial. We use simple broadcasting as noted below. However, for multi-dimensional arrays, the answer is not evident to me. So, how do I this, preferably using numpy?

Example (EDITED):

```
a1 = np.array of size 20x3 # so that each row is a 3-vector
a2 = np.array of size 20x3 # ditto

def f(x, y): # acts on each element 
   ... complicated function, using other global variables ...
   return ... (scalar)
```

Without vectorisation, I need to loop `f` individually over all 20 rows, and get an output length 20 vector:

```
result = []
for i, elem in a1:
    result.append(f(elem, a2[i]))
result = np.array(result)
```

However, I want to eliminate the `for` loop, and have a single statement, using numpy vectorisation. The reason is to be able to use the numpy wrapper of `jax` (https://github.com/google/jax) then to speed this up on a GPU. Something naive like

```
result = f(a1, a2)
```

does not work. So what is the correct syntax?

Comment: I think you want `numpy.apply_along_axis` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html

Comment: What would be the operation? Maybe the question is more about broadcasting https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html?highlight=broadcasting#module-numpy.doc.broadcasting?

Comment: I just added a schematic example to clarify what I mean

Comment: Strongly depends on how `f` looks like, as Christian K. wrote. np.vectorize` is just hiding the loop, see my comment on the answer. Best way would be to just use pure vectorized Numpy functions and broadcasting. Show `f()` and we can provide further help.

Comment: Clarify what dimensions your function can handle.  scalar, 1d, 2d etc.  Does it handle broadcasting?  It's hard to give meaningful answers without a clear example.

Comment: There isn't a general way of speeding things up.  Either write `f` such that it handles the 3d and 2d arrays (e.g. with broadcasting), or use a compilation tool like `numba` or `cython`.

Comment: I am sorry for all the confusion. I think I have finally edited the question to be sufficiently clear, without having extraneous details. Please take a look above. The speed-up is not the issue here. I intend to use `jax` for that. I just need the proper syntax for a `numpy` function that can do what I ask.

Comment: Just wrap your `result` loop code in a function definition!

Comment: Do you know how to make a simple function that works with your mix of dimensions?  Earlier you have `a1` (20,3,2) and `a2` (20,2)`.  `a1*a2[:,None,:]` is elementwise multiplication.  `np.einsum('ijk,ik->i`,a1,a2)` produces a 1d array.  When you understand how that kind of calculation works you have a chance of replacing your loop with a properly 'vectorized' equivalent.

Comment: @hpaulj OK, I will try to understand how these statements work then.

Answer (score 0):

use numpy's [vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html).

A simple example of `np.vectorize` using a simple lambda function:

```
import numpy as np
f = np.vectorize(lambda x: 2*x)
f([[2,3],[3,4],[1,1]])
# output:
array([[4, 6],
       [6, 8],
       [2, 2]])
```

Comment: This does not solve it if your are aiming for performance. From the [`doc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html): The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

Comment: Right, when i answered the author did not edit the question up to the point where he talks about "speeding up things" i.e. performance..

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the operation you need to execute, if it was a simple sum than the following will work:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(3*2*20).reshape((20,3,2))
b = np.arange(2*20).reshape((20,2))

res = (a.transpose((1,2,0))+b.transpose((1,0))).transpose((2,0,1))
print(a[0],b[0])

[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]] [0 1]

print(res[0])

[[0 2]
 [2 4]
 [4 6]]
```

First the input data is transposed so that the correct dimensions will be involved in the broadcasted operation. After summation, the output is tranposed back.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been trying to do something similar over the past few days. I finally managed to do it with `np.vectorize`, using [function signatures](https://numpy.org/doc/1.17/reference/c-api.generalized-ufuncs.html). Try with the code snippet below:

```
fn_vectorized = np.vectorize(interpolate.interp1d,
                                     signature='(n),(n)->()')
interp_fn_array = fn_vectorized(x[np.newaxis, :, :], y)
```

Here, I was doing the vectorization of the interp1d function. x and y are arrays of shape (m x n). The objective was to generate an array of interpolation functions, for row *i* of x and row *i* of y. The array 'interp_fn_array' contains the interpolation functions (shape is (1 x m).